# Combining 2 values within a set of identifiers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to do this in PHP but I'm working on a javascript array and it is giving me alot of trouble.

I have an array that will always be set up like this:

```
array[0] => Keyword
array[1] => String 1
array[2] => String 2
array[3] => String 3
array[4] => Keyword
array[5] => String 4
array[6] => String 5
array[7] => Keyword
```

Now this can go on for awhile, so my question is how can I automatically parse this array so that it no longer includes Keyword and combines the values within the Keywords, ie: String 1+2+3 is 1 whole string, and String 4+5 is one whole string together.

Comment: How would you do it in PHP? It's probably very similar...

Comment: @Honzo could you give an example of the output array?

Comment: the output array would be:

`keywords[0] => String 1 String 2 String 3
keywords[1] => String 4 String 5`

Comment: @FelixKling with PHP I could just use explode() and it would easily allow me to manipulate the array a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if keyword is not present in the strings then you can do it with

```
array.join("").split("Keyword")
```

(have to get rid of possible empty first and last elements, also) Otherwise, if you could find two characters not present in the strings or keyword, e.g. `#` and `%`, you could do it like this:

```
array.join("#").replace(/(^|#)Keyword(#|$)/g, "%").replace(/#/g, "").split("%")
```

Comment: beat me to it. If the array starts and ends with 'Keyword', then you can use shift() and pop() to trim off the empty elements. However, my guess is that a more robust solution is needed to avoid non-keyword array elements that contain the keyword

Comment: With this particular set,the elements will never contain Keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
function transformArr(inputArr) {
    var resultArr = [];
    var buildString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (inputArr[i] == 'Keyword') {
            if (buildString != "") {
                resultArr.push(buildString);
                buildString = "";
            }
        } else {
            buildString += inputArr[i];
        }
    }
    if (buildString != "") {
        resultArr.push(buildString);
    }
    return resultArr;
}
array = [];
array[0] = 'Keyword';
array[1] = 'String 1';
array[2] = 'String 2';
array[3] = 'String 3';
array[4] = 'Keyword';
array[5] = 'String 4';
array[6] = 'String 5';
array[7] = 'Keyword';

var result = transformArr(array);
console.log(result);
```